# How to convert byte[] to textual representation of byte code in Java?

Tags: java, java-bytecode-asm, byte-buddy

I have a `byte[]` that represents `HelloWorld.class` now I want to convert into say a String that represents a bytecode(similar to `javap -c HelloWorld.class`)? And I want to do this programmatically.

Simply put I want to go from

`byte[]` to `String` that represents `javap -c HelloWorld.class`

and

bytecode `String` back to `byte[]`

Note: All done programatically so I dont want to invoke anything through command line

Open to any well known standard libraries like asm or bytebuddy.

Comment: This seems to be an answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14451505/547270

Comment: "Open to any well known standard libraries" Questions asking for library recommendations are off-topic for StackOverflow.

Comment: @Michael they weren't asking for a library recommendation, they were asking for a solution and stating that there were no constraints on what library to use.

Comment: The problem statement is not entirely clear. Does the `byte[]` contain the *whole class file data*, or only the data from the [code attribute](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.7.3)? The main issue is: The output of `javap` is not "reversible" in that sense. You cannot create a full-fledged Java class from the `javap` output.

Comment: Well, how complicated should it be? How about just writing the bytes to a temporary file and actually running `javap` as sub-process? With recent Java versions, it’s close to a one-liner…

Answer (score 0):

Using ASM, try creating a `ClassReader` over the `byte[]` representation of the class, then calling `ClassReader.accept()`, supplying a `TraceClassVisitor` as the `ClassVisitor` argument.

(Not tested. We use most of these components, but not in quite this combination.)